# State Covid-19 cases

Tags: data

The aim of the function below is to take a state US s and county c and return the total number of covid-19 cases.

```
    data=ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", \
    "USStates"]

  usaStateCases[s_,c_] :=
 First[data[Select[MatchQ[Interpreter["USState"][s], #State] &]][
     Select[MatchQ[
        Interpreter["USCounty"][c <> " county, " <> s], #County] &]][
    All, #ConfirmedCases["LastValue"] &] // Normal, 0]
```

How can this be modified to remove county entirely and just focus on states?  TIA

Comment: A hint: `Interpreter["USState"]["Washington" <> " state"]`

Comment: I want to be looking at more than just Washington State.  What I want is a function of s, the state, that gives total cases of virus on record for s, not just one state.

Comment: Obviously yes, just replace `"Washington"` with `s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", "USStates"];

usaStateCases[s_] := 
 Select[data, MatchQ[Interpreter["USState"][s], First[#]] &][
    All, #ConfirmedCases["LastValue"] &] // Normal // First

usaStateDeaths[s_] := 
 Select[data, MatchQ[Interpreter["USState"][s], First[#]] &][
    All, #Deaths["LastValue"] &] // Normal // First

usaStateCases["Iowa"] (* result: 26469 *)

usaStateDeaths["Iowa"] (* result: 689 *)
```

Comment: Your code above does not work at MMA v 11.3. Here are some errors that came out:  `Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {$Failed} cannot be transposed.
Set::shape: Lists {DataResource`Private`locations,DataResource`Private`formats} and Transpose[{$Failed}] are not the same shape.
Import::chtype: First argument DataResource`Private`locations is not a valid file, directory, or URL specification.
Select::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Select[$Failed,MatchQ[Interpreter[USState][Iowa],First[#1]]&].`

Comment: @TugrulTemel Worked perfectly fine for me in 12.2 giving value 5725 today. Version 11.3 is from 2018 - perhaps this dataset of the 2020 pandemic doesn't work with older versions for some reason, hence the $Failed.